# Processing.js missing mouse position when scrolling in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, processing.js

Processing.js running on Google Chrome is not going to correctly get the mouse position when you use the scroll bar. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pokipsy/4EHEW/1/)

```
void setup(){
    size(300,300);
}
void draw() {
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,10,10);
}
```

shrink the window enough to make the scroll bar appear, then scroll a little bit down and look at what happens to the mouse position detection. Firefox and explorer don't have the problem.

Does anybody know how to solve the issue?

Comment: this works fine for me in Chrome 33.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome 33 as well, but I had a similar issue when I first started using Processing.js. I added:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML >`

to the top of the html page and it seemed to work. I can't seem to remember where I found the solution or else I would link it. That being said, it seems to be working in Chrome 33 without it (I was probably on an earlier version when I had the issue).